# How to keep vehicles upgrades equipped in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: android, jetpack-joyride

I have Jetpack Joyride for Android, but every time I start the game I have to equip the magnetic upgrades to all vehicles, except the teleporter, which is the only one already equipped.

I had once a game crash that undid my last 2 magnets purchases, so I ended up with only the teleporter and 20k less in cash. After that, I've bought every vehicle magnet, but still the only one that will remain equipped is the teleport.

Anyone already found some similar bug? How could I fix this, it's kinda annoying have to mannually enable 5 different upgrades every time I want to play.

Comment: Does the Android version support save backup like the iOS version does? If so, I'd try deleting the game and reinstalling again

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't, and I'm not willing to delete my save just for that. Today I tried to clean the cache (Jetpack was using almost 30mb of cache, what the hell), but that also didn't work. I'll keep trying simple stuff like equipping/unequipping them in a row, or leave the game with everything unequipped, to see it these things work. If not, well, I'll just forget about it...

Comment: I don't own an Android device, so I don't know it's possible to do so, butI would check online for methods to backups the game's save externally, reinstall the app then try to restore the save. I think that's your best bet

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue.  I've found that sometimes my clothing changes to a previous setting, my money changes to previous times, and my rewards will disappear.  Even though this is an older question, I really wanted to say that I had also experienced it.  What I do to alleviate it is to make sure to go back to the Jetpack Joyride 'Home' screen and then push my device's 'Back' button until the program asks if I want to quit.  This seems to work well enough.

Answer (score 1):

My magnets were disappearing as well within the Vehicle Upgrades. I found that if you uninstall, then reinstall-- it seems to have fixed the problem. 
You stated that you don't want to lose your saved progress, and you don't have to. If you create a profile-- located on the home menu, you'll be able to keep your progress saved using your own account online. As you uninstall or even switch to a new device, you'll be able to upload your saved progress.

Comment: I asked this 2 years ago, the game didn't have profile back then. Also, this issue is not affecting me anymore, but thanks, this might help someone else.